# como remover correctamente el texto de mi lista y añadir nuevos elementos

Tags: javascript, setattribute

Estoy tratando de con javascript eliminar el texto de esta lista:

```
            <ul>
                <li class="mueble">Mesa</li>
                <li class="escolar">Libreta</li>
                <li class="escolar">Lapiz</li>
                <li class="electrodomestico">Ventilador</li>
                <li class="electrico">Enchufe</li>
                <li class="decoracion">Alfombra</li>
                <li class="television">Mando</li>
                <li class="decoracion">Ambientador</li>
                <li class="electrico">Cable</li>
                <li class="electrico">Lampara</li>
            </ul>
```

he creado un script que pasados 3 segundos pregunta algo si le damos a confirmar debería borrar todos los textos de li y dejar los li vacios pero no se muy bien como hacer esto correctamente.

```js
setTimeout(() => confirm('confirmas?'), 3000);
if (confirm) {
  document.getElementsByTagName(li).removeAttribute('class');
}
```

después quiero añadir un nuevo valor a cada li he pensado en usar

```
elemento. setAttribute("Mesa", "Alfombra");
```

Pero nose si esto es correcto, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Añado otra respuesta de acuerdo a el ejercicio que requieres hacer, comentado para ver si de esa manera es más claro:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <ui>
        <li class="mueble">Mesa</li>
        <li class="escolar">Libreta</li>
        <li class="escolar">Lapiz</li>
        <li class="electrodomestico">Ventilador</li>
        <li class="electrico">Enchufe</li>
        <li class="decoracion">Alfombra</li>
        <li class="television">Mando</li>
        <li class="decoracion">Ambientador</li>
        <li class="electrico">Cable</li>
        <li class="electrico">Lampara</li>
    </ui>

    <script>
        // Definimos el array de valores nuevos (no importa el orden)
        objetos = [
            'Mesa',
            'Libreta',
            'Lapiz',
            'Ventilador',
            'Enchufe',
            'Alfombra',
            'Mando',
            'Ambientador',
            'Cable',
            'Lampara'
        ];
        // Establecemos el tiempo de 3s
        setTimeout(function () {
            // Lanzamos mensaje de confirmación
            result = confirm('Confirmas?');
            // Si acepta...
            if (result == true) {
                // Obtenemos los elementos por la etiqueta 'li'
                list = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
                // Comenzamos un bucle donde la cantidad de iteraciones sea la longitud de la colección
                for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                    // Guardamos el li actual en la variable element
                    const element = list[i];
                    // Al elemento actual le asignamos el texto '' (que sería dejarlo en blanco)
                    element.innerHTML = '';
                }
            }

            setTimeout(function () {
                // *****Para asignar los valores ordenados después de haber borrado*****
                // Confirm para ordenar
                ordenar = confirm('Mostrar los elementos ordenados?');
                // Si acepta...
                if (ordenar == true) {
                    // ordenamos los objetos con la función sort
                    objetos.sort();
                    // tomamos de nuevo los elementos li
                    list = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
                    // Como ya sabemos que la cantidad de elementos en el array y los elementos li son los mismos, usamos un solo bucle
                    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                        // guarda el elemento li actual en la variable element
                        const element = list[i];
                        // Al elemento li actual, le vamos a asignar de texto, el valor en la posisión [i] del array de objetos (previamente ordenado)
                        element.innerHTML = objetos[i];

                    }
                }
            }, 3000);

        }, 3000)
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: wau muchas gracias!!! me he hecho una idea de como debía funcionar!! estaba revisando los apuntes que nos paso el profesor pero no lograba entender nada!!!! He modificado mi codigo en base a tu respuesta una vez la he entendido y ya funciona correctamente!

Answer (score 1):

El setAttribute es como bien lo dice, añadir un atributo a la etiqueta, lo que tu ejemplo haría (si seleccionaras un solo "li") sería lo siguiente: `<li mesa>Texto de Lista </li>`

En cuanto al **setTimeout**, te recomiendo que uses las funciones de manera tradicional si aún no estás familiarizado con las funciones flecha, ya que la condición al confirmar la estás estableciendo fuera de donde declaraste el confirm, y al no guardarlo dentro de una variable, estarías e

Por lo cual, si estás obteniendo todos los elementos

es necesario que recorras con un bucle los mismos y elimines el valor con **innerHTML**, para asignar un nuevo valor, tendrías que hacer lo mismo:

```
    <ui>
        <li>Texto1</li>
        <li>Texto2</li>
        <li>Texto3</li>
        <li>Texto4</li>
        <li>Texto5</li>
        <li>Texto6</li>
    </ui>
    
<script>
    
    setTimeout( function () {
        result = confirm('Confirmas?');
        if(result == true) {
            list = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
            console.log(list);
            for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                const element = list[i];
                element.innerHTML = '';
                
            }
        }
    }, 3000)
</script>
```

Comment: Hola!!! muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta es super util para mi!!! ya que no sabia ya como eliminar las palabras, tengo una pregunta si quisiera añadir unas nuevas palabras como se haría ??? esta bine usar setattribute?

Comment: No, usuar setAttribute como te comenté en la respuesta, no añade el texto dentro de la etiqueta <li>, tendrías que hacer el mismo proceso del bucle, si te fijas, para limpiar, dentro del ciclo y teniendo ya un solo elemento seleccionado, usé innerHTML, con esto asignas que quiers que esté dentro del elemento, por lo que tendrías que hacer algo como "elemento.innerHTML = 'mesa'.

Comment: mmm entonces debería meter por ejemplo 10 elemento.innerHTML ? o puedo hacer por ejemplo un array dentro del innerHTML ? en plan  elemento.innerHTML = ["mesa","alfombra","lapiz"] ??

Comment: Hay que aclarar una cosa primero, quieres cambiar el texto del elemento o bien, cambiar el valor de los atributos (que en este caso serian las clases)?

Comment: quiero cambiar el texto, me han pedido que lo saque ordenado alfabeticamente, después de borrarlo, he estado probando el inerHTML pero solo me deja introducir una linea no termino de entenderlo

Comment: Añadí otra respuestá para ver si soluciona mejor el problema y tus dudas